# Android:Change button background in listview

Tags: android, android-listview

In listview have 4 buttons as follow

```
B1 B2 B3 B4
B1 B2 B3 B4
B1 B2 B3 B4
B1 B2 B3 B4
```

if user clicks first row button B2 other buttons in same rows has to change their color (B1 B3 B4)

and onclick done in xml. and its get fire too but problem is if I click in row1 B1 its get affected in other rows

```
public void clickbutton(View v){
int position = homelist.getPositionForView(v);
View parent = homelist.getChildAt(position);

_resetAllButton(parent);
v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green);
}


private void _resetAllButton(View v){
    ((Button)v.findViewById(R.id.lay1btn_a5)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.alarmbtn);
    ((Button)v.findViewById(R.id.lay1btn_a15)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.alarmbtn);
    ((Button)v.findViewById(R.id.lay1btn_a30)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.alarmbtn);
    ((Button)v.findViewById(R.id.lay1btn_a45)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.alarmbtn);


}
```

Help needy. Thank!

Comment: Have you used custom adapter if yes then please post that code in your question. Your this code is not enough to analyze the problem.

Comment: What do you want exactly?

Comment: I guess you need to implement custom Adapter for your listview.

Comment: I tried same with custom adapter and as though its leaves same output
http://pastie.org/8703500